# Setting EVP_PKEY_RSA_PSS key type to EVP_PKEY* object leads to segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography, segmentation-fault, public-key-encryption

I have a C code which creates a public key from exponent and modulus of a JWK data. Leave about JWK data here.

here the generated public key is in EVP_PKEY* format and its type is "EVP_PKEY_RSA" which is ID 6. I am trying to change its type to EVP_PKEY_RSA_PSS which is ID 912.

For setting key type, I am using

EVP_PKEY_set_type(pRsaKey, EVP_PKEY_RSA_PSS); function.

this function sets the key type properly. But after done this, looks like pRsaKey gets corrupted. Not able to do any further operation. I tried writing this key to a file like,

```
int generate_pubkey(char* exponent, char* modulus, EVP_PKEY** pubkey) {
    BIGNUM *n = bignum_base64_decode(modulus);
    BIGNUM *e = bignum_base64_decode(exponent);
    int ret = 0;

    if (!e || !n) {
        printf("Error: Invalid encoding for public exponent or modulus\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (e && n) {
        EVP_PKEY* pRsaKey = EVP_PKEY_new();
        RSA* rsa = RSA_new();

        if (!RSA_set0_key(rsa, n, e, NULL)) {
            printf("\nError: Failed to set RSA key components");
            BN_free(n);
            BN_free(e);
            RSA_free(rsa);
            return 1;
        }
        EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(pRsaKey, rsa);
        printf("PKEY ID: %d\n", EVP_PKEY_id(pRsaKey));  //here it is 6
        EVP_PKEY_set_type(pRsaKey, EVP_PKEY_RSA_PSS);
        printf("PKEY ID: %d\n", EVP_PKEY_id(pRsaKey));  //here it is 912

        FILE* fp = fopen("pubnew.key", "w");
        if (!fp) {
              printf("Failed to open file for writing");
              return 0;
        }
        ret = PEM_write_PUBKEY(fp, pRsaKey); //getting segmentation fault here
        fclose(fp);

        return 0;
    }
```

Solution tried:
Instead of changing the key type directly. I created a new EVP_PKEY object, copy all the parameters and then set the keytype to the newly created object. there also it throws segmentation fault.

```
int generate_pubkey(char* exponent, char* modulus, EVP_PKEY** pubkey) {
    BIGNUM *n = bignum_base64_decode(modulus);
    BIGNUM *e = bignum_base64_decode(exponent);
    int ret = 0;

    if (!e || !n) {
        printf("Error: Invalid encoding for public exponent or modulus\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (e && n) {
        EVP_PKEY* pRsaKey = EVP_PKEY_new();
        RSA* rsa = RSA_new();

        if (!RSA_set0_key(rsa, n, e, NULL)) {
            printf("\nError: Failed to set RSA key components");
            BN_free(n);
            BN_free(e);
            RSA_free(rsa);
            return 1;
        }
        EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(pRsaKey, rsa);
        printf("PKEY ID: %d\n", EVP_PKEY_id(pRsaKey)); //here it is 6

        // Copy the key parameters to *pubkey
        *pubkey = EVP_PKEY_new();
        EVP_PKEY_copy_parameters(*pubkey, pRsaKey);
        EVP_PKEY_set_type(*pubkey, EVP_PKEY_RSA_PSS);
        printf("PKEY ID: %d\n", EVP_PKEY_id(*pubkey));  ///here it becomes 912
           
        FILE* fp = fopen("pubnew.key", "w");
        if (!fp) {
                printf("Failed to open file for writing");
                return 0;
        }
        ret = PEM_write_PUBKEY(fp, *pubkey); //segmentation fault here
        fclose(fp);

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs for `EVP_PKEY_set_type()`:

> EVP_PKEY_set_type() initialises pkey to contain an internal legacy key.

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man3/EVP_PKEY_set_type.html

The *initialises* is significant here. Basically that function is re-initialising your `EVP_PKEY` and dropping the `RSA` data from it - giving you an empty RSA_PSS key. It's segfaulting when you call `PEM_write_PUBKEY()` because the `RSA` key data is NULL.

Instead you should assign it to the correct type in the first place, e.g. via `EVP_PKEY_assign(pRsaKey, EVP_PKEY_RSA_PSS, rsa);`

Note that many of the calls you are using are deprecated in OpenSSL 3.0

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. EVP_PKEY_assign(pRsaKey, EVP_PKEY_RSA_PSS, rsa); this worked for me.